# Filtro Cut Bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash, filtro, cut

Estoy realizando un script en bash y estoy utilizando el filtro "cut" para extraer información del comando `ls -l`.

El problema es que cuando la fecha es un solo dígito (por ejemplo 1, 2 o 6) la linea incluye dos espacios en blancos seguidos y cuando son 2 dígitos (por ejemplo 12, 25, 29) la línea incluye un solo espacio en blanco.
Quisiera saber como resolver este problema.

Adjunto porción del código:

```
ls -l ./archivos_sec | cut -d " " -f 9
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada sobre por qué no debe parsearse el resultado de `ls`: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Mejor extraer los datos de otras maneras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen muchas maneras de resolverlo, pero la mas comoda para mi siempre es mudarme al awk:
Puedes hacerlo especificando el 'Field separator' con la opcion -F

```sh
# Similar a cut -d " "
ls -l archivos_sec | awk -F " " '{print $7}'
```

O Simplemente puedes hacerlo sin especifar el 'Field separator' ya que el field separator de awk siempre son los espacios (sin importar cuantos)

```sh
ls -l archivos_sec | awk '{print $7}'
```

¿Por que **$7** y no **$9**?

Por que a cut le dices que el delimitador es **un** espacio mientras que awk entiende que son todos los espacios hasta que se encuentre con un caracter que no sea un espacio.
Por ejemplo haces un ls -l en la carpeta raiz del sistema y te fijas en la segunda columna y notas que la segunda columna seguido de **uno** o **mas** espacios tiene numeros de uno, dos y tres caracteres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego lo si lo filtramos con cut nos damos cuenta de que la segunda columna son solamente las que tienen **tres** dijitos, pues desde la *x* de la primera columna hasta el primer dijito de la segunda columna existe apenas un espacio y esa seria nuestra columna **dos** para `cut -d " "` (El 72 de arriba no cuenta pues viene de la segunda columna de la primera linea que nos marca el total de archivos en nuestra carpeta raiz):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la tercera columna para `cut -d " "` sera la que tiene **dos** dijitos y los 'root' de las lineas donde su columna 2 consta de 3 dijitos, lo podemos ver mas claro si lo filtramos con `cat -n` para ver que numero de linea es exactamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en las mismas lineas *6* y *16* tenemos a 'root', ¿coincidencia?, no lo creo, `cut -d " "` hace exactamente lo que le pedimos.
Ahora vemos que esto no pasa con awk y por eso es mi favorito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Creo que `cut` sólo va a funcionar con un carácter de separador. Para más, hay que usar algo más flexible.

Por ejemplo

```
ls -l ./directorio | awk '{print $6 $7}'
```

Debería imprimir

```
ago16
dic22
nov11
oct2
sep12
oct7
sep25...
```

Si necesitas algo de formato en la salida, puedes valerte de printf

```
ls -l ~ | awk '{printf "%s %s\n", $6, $7}'
```

Que entrega algo como

```
ago 16
dic 22
nov 11
oct 2
sep 12
oct 7
sep 25
jul 30
nov 10
sep 25...
```

Comment: esto es muy frágil... [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Mejor extraer los datos de otras maneras.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' gracias!

Answer (score 3):

El formato de salida de `ls` no es apropiado para procesarlo con `cut`. Una alternativa más flexible y poderosa es analizar la salida de `find` que te permitirá darle un formato específico a las fechas de acceso de los archivos:

`find ./directorio -maxdepth 1  -printf "%M|%n|%u|%s|%Ac|%P\n" | cut -d "|" -f 5`

Puedes ver el [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) de find para más detalles.

Comment: bien por señalar que no conviene parsear la salida de `ls`. En lugar de `find`, también puedes usar por ejemplo `for file in *; do "cosas con $file"; done`.